# Issue with Machine, not sure if power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

Friend of mine has a rig that has just mysteriously "stopped working".  I wasn't there when this occured, so I've decided to take a look at it.

Upon trying to turn it on, the fan on the back of the PSU spins for a quick moment and then stops. At this point I decided further investigation was needed.

Popped off the side panel.  Notice a light on the MoBo is on, press the button to turn the machine on - the fan on the CPU spins for a quick moment and then stops as well.

I'm fairly sure it's the PSU but don't have a back-up to test with.

Thoughts?

Comment: 1) Do you by chance have another system you could plug THIS PwrSpply into? Bear in mind that could be a tiny risk if the PwrSpply is bad... although I don't think MUCH of a risk. 2) Do you have another box that maybe is running that you could just temporarily borrow the PwrSpply from just to test this? 3) You sound pretty solid so... I am assuming you checked all the connectors to make sure they are firmly seated and not just "look like they are good"?

Comment: Ya, I only have a laptop at my place.  Friend has desktop and laptop.  I'll go get a PSU and swap its out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick fan spin can mean PSU, as you suggest, or it could mean MoBo. MoBo light probably just indicates the MoBo is receiving power. Whether it is receiving *enough* power would be a question.

In this case I'd say it's most likely PSU. They also tend to be easier to acquire, swap, and test (and return if it turns out not to be the case).

Comment: Agreed that this may be the motherboard (or potentially even CPU but that's really unlikely)

Comment: Hey Hack... since I didn't post the stuff like THIS answer did it's less accurate?  You choice but I totally disagree.  My answer was just as helpful as this one except it didn't pretend to be more of answer than it was.  And this answer certainly shows no more specific information than mine did.

Comment: On a side note, all the suggestions THIS answer makes are pure conjecture.  If my post was deleted this should have been next.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be some other component. To check, remove the memory, cards, disk connectors, etc. and try booting with just the processor. If it boots (though expect some beeps) add components back one at time.

If the PSU has a voltage switch on the back, you may want to check that too.

Comment: Excellent suggestions.. especially the voltage switch.. I've seen that one before and totally forgot to mention it :)